# Podcatcher/Podplayer that syncs position across machines and devices?

Tags: sync, podcasts

I have multiple computers that I am on in a given day. Macbook in the morning, Macbook Pro at work, iPhone when out and about and an iMac in the evening. I listen to a range of podcasts through the day and want to not have to remember what minute I was at in any given podcast when I move between machines. I keep the subscriptions the same on all of the machines via OPML when I add a new show.

Is there a service or application that can sync the time listened on a given podcast across machines? Even to an iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything that advanced (though it would be cool). Your best bet is an iPod or iPhone if you want to do that. Then sync it up to get your new podcasts every day.

Answer (score 0):

If you use, or are willing to switch to Google Reader for your subscriptions, then Aopcalypse Interrupted makes a neat product called [Play, Look, and Listen](http://www.apocalypseinterrupted.com/products/play-look-and-listen) that syncs your position whenever you pause the podcast.

It has an iOS and Android app, and the desktop client runs on Silverlight, so it will work on Windows and OS X.